# Click on table causes multiple ajax operations are running with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

after looking for a solution of a problem I may found the turning point and can define the problem.
My code uses jQuery and Ajax and is triggered on a click on a table cell. The output was and is a table which I refresh within an interval.
Well, when I clicked on a cell and then on another cell the output is switching between the outputs based on the transmitted value of cell A and cell B.

I took a look into firebug and, voila, got a sneak on the reason.

```
GET http://localhost/trading/getuser_exp.php?q=NYSE
GET http://localhost/trading/getuser_exp.php?q=NASDAQ
```

Both values are running parallel and this is wrong. I need a single value or, in other words, if I clicked on NYSE before, value is NYSE, then I click on NASDAQ, the value isn't NYSE anymore, but NASDAQ.

The code is use is

```
$(document).ready(function(){


$(".information").click(function () {
var str = $(this).closest("tr").find("#nr").text(); 

window.setInterval(function(){      
          $.get("getuser_exp.php",
             { q:str },
             function(data) { $('.stock').html(data);
             } //function data

          );
}, 3000);


}); //information click


}); //document ready
```

Now what causes the multiple firing? In my eyes - frank speaking a beginner - nothing is multiple firing or that is accepting multiple values. Whatever it is, I will learn.

Thank you for any assistance and help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear the old interval and start a new one. This is why you get multiple firings as each click starts a new interval timer.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var timer = null;
   $(".information").click(function () {
      var str = $(this).closest("tr").find("#nr").text(); 
      if(timer!=null) {
         clearInterval(timer);
      }
      timer = window.setInterval(function(){      
         $.get("getuser_exp.php",
           { q:str },
           function(data) { 
              $('.stock').html(data);
           }
         );
      }, 3000);
   }); 
});
```

Comment: It works!!!! Great! Thank you, Patrick. I will analyze your solution and learn for the future. Really thanks.